# Is it possible to connect your MAMP localhost to FTP for quick upload?

Tags: git, ftp, webserver, mamp

When I want to upload some files that I have tested with MAMP on my localhost, I have to go through a strenuous process of finding the files and then uploading them to the relevant directory using my FTP client FileZilla.

Is there a way to prevent having to do this and have some way of uploading the file to my FTP server when I want?

Would it be worth using git to upload the files via `git push`?

Thanks in advanced.

XcodeDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git push` would actually not work, at least not by itself. Pushing only updates the refs on the remote side, but not the working tree, so your changes would not be effected.

You could, however, probably add that functionality using a hook script, in which case it would certainly be a convenient solution if you're already using Git.

The easiest solution, on the other hand, might be to simply use `scp` to upload the files (since you say that you could use `git push`, I assume you have SSH access), keep the terminal open, and repeat the command any number of times.